# Convert jpql query to Criteria api

Tags: java, spring-data, jpql, criteria-api

I have two Entities with both Many-to-Many relations:

```
@Entity
public class Medicament {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
@Entity
public class Ingredient {
    @Id
    private String ingredient;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Medicament> medicaments = new ArrayList<>();

    public Ingredient(String ingredient) {
        this.ingredient = ingredient;
    }
}
```

I want to get medicaments that have ingredients from List req, all of them or at least one.
So I wrote these queries:

1. '*select med from Medicament med where (select count(ing) from med.ingredients ing where ing in :req) > 0*' -- at least one
2. '*select med from Medicament med where (select count(ing) from med.ingredients ing where ing in :req) = :req_count*' -- all of them
   They works fine.
   How convert these where parts to spring data Specification?

I tried this one:

```
(root, cq, cb) -> {
   Subquery<Long> subQuery = cq.subquery(Long.class);
   Root<Ingridient> subRoot = subQuery.from(Ingridient.class);
   subQuery = subQuery.select(cb.count(subRoot)).where(subRoot.in(medicamentRequest.getIngridients()));
   if (isAll) {
      return cb.equal(subQuery, medicamentRequest.getIngridients().size());
   } else {
      return cb.gt(subQuery, 0);
   }
}
```

But it throws this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.type.internal.NamedBasicTypeImpl cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EntityValuedModelPart (org.hibernate.type.internal.NamedBasicTypeImpl and org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EntityValuedModelPart are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```